# How Can I run a user command by using their ID (Ex - /ban 696053906010276010)?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
let fUser = message.guild.member(message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]))

if (!fUser) 
    return message.channel.send("Please put a valid member or a user ID for me to strike").then(msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 8000 })).catch(console.error);
```

How can I like ban someone using their id cause currently how my user variable is setup is it only allows me to ban them by mentioning but I want to be able to ban them by ID instead the only way I can do that right now to replace "user" with their id like this <@716382720917372998>.

But I just want to put in there raw ID and it works out.

Comment: Fetch by the given id and resolve the promise. `message.guild.members.fetch(args[0])`

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: Did you resolve the promise? `let fUser; message.guild.members.fetch(args[0]).then( member => fUser = member)`

Comment: `let fUser = message.guild.members.fetch(args[0]).then( member => fUser = member)` still doesn't work.

Comment: We need more information than "doesn't work" to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

In order to ban a user by their ID you have to do the following :

```js
const member =  message.mentions.members.first() || await message.guild.members.fetch(args[0]);
```

Here the member variable is an GuildMember so you can just do `member.ban()` to ban them.

Comment: `.fetch()` has to be resolved before invoking `ban()`

Comment: sorry my bad i forgot to add `await` but now i did it.